# CSS - SVG border overflow

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a border as a SVG file, which i want to place over another image. I use position absolute to place it on top of the image. However, I have a problem with the image on the bottom is overflowing, because the top image has transparent areas around it. I would like to only show the bottom image inside of the border, so it's black around it.

Changing the svg file is not an option, because there will be background image instead of the black color.

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.item-container {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 275px;
}

.item-container .item-image {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 275px;
}

.item-container .item-border {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  max-height: 275px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 item-container">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/290x275" class="item-image" alt="">
        <img src="https://svgur.com/i/92T.svg" alt="" class="item-border">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a clipping effect. - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/

Answer (score -1):

You could try using background-image instead of using a static image as the border. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: I cant really see how that would change anything. Can you please explain?

Comment: Ahh okay now I see what you mean sorry I will try to solve it

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out, maybe you could do it with calc or with jquery